# Why aren't my answers migrated from a site to EE appear on the "Top Questions/Answers" Page?

Tags: bug, profile-page, migration, network-profile, top-answers

Okay: here's the situation. I participated on an Area 51 site that was closed, and migrated. However, in the process, there was some bugs.

**Here's what has happened:**

- All my questions were migrated successfully. They all were migrated to either SO, EE, or Robotics (it was a post under 5 votes).
- The question migrated to SO "Top Question" worthy was put on the list.
- All Reputation was added properly.
- My questions/answers migrated to EE were however not added to this list, even though they are over 5.

I know this should be there because the one for SO did this.

[**Top Questions/answers page**](https://stackexchange.com/users/1640390/annonomus-person?tab=top)

[**EE Profile**](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/18442/annonomus-person?tab=summary)

---

I didn't post this on EE Meta because, although this deals with EE, this is the *Network Profile*, **it's not something directly relating to EE.**

---

**Edit:** Someone downvoted my SO question... oh well. :( I just wanted to post this so no one got confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Somehow, they randomly appeared a couple of months later. I don't know what happened there.**